# Solving $(x + a_i)$ mod $n_i \equiv 0$ for $x$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The typical system of congruence equations addressed by the CRT looks like
$$
x \equiv a_i \text{ mod } n_i 
$$
Is there a way to use those or similar techniques to tackle something of this form?
$$
(x + a_i) \equiv 0 \text{ mod } n_i
$$

Comment: Yes. Your equation is same as $x \equiv -a_i$ mod $n_i.$

Comment: well that was very easy...should have seen that..